# Is this pinyin alphabet used to spell in Chinese Sign Language? Otherwise, which one is used in Mainland China?

Tags: pinyin

Is this pinyin alphabet used to spell in Chinese Sign Language? Otherwise, which one is used in Mainland China?

[image]

Comment: I don’t speak Chinese sign language, but the figure caption says »Chinese sign language alphabet«, and the special signs for Chinese letter combinations that are explicitly part of *Hanyu pinyin* (zh, ch, sh, ng) (it est: mainland China) sort of give it away, too. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: @Philipp it's the only sorce, which for the most widely spoken language in the world is quite suspicious.

Comment: I don't think that depends on Mainland China/Taiwan/Hongkong

Answer (score 1):

This matches some intro materials I was shown in Changchun. I think it's the mainland standard. It's also repeated in a few places around the net if you baidu it.

I have to say though, the standardization of Chinese sign language is a work in progress, the signers I met in Changchun were an extremely heterogeneous bunch language-wise, it was amazing the sheer diversity of signs they would accept for common phrases. And pinyin was not exactly their favorite toolkit, it's much harder to remember if you're deaf. So your mileage on the ground may vary, good luck with this project, whatever it is!